# Absolute path in angular cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am using angular cli for my angular 2 application. After npm run build, dist folder is created. When I open index.html of dist folder, it cannot find files like inline.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js etc. I need to give an absolute path for these files so that I can run my project. Please help.

Comment: In order to build angular cli project, you should run `ng build` command.

Comment: @Darshita I have built the project. The relative path of mentioned files are the issue.

Comment: Have you published your dist folder?

Comment: @Darshita not really. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: From where you are browsing your index.html ?Have you published dist folder in any web server?

Comment: @Darshita I am using static web hosting in Azure. So accessing directly from dist folder.

Comment: What absolute path you need for files like inline.bundle.js?

Comment: possibly your problem related with base href. check the cli --base-href option

Comment: @Darshita as per the structure the script I include in index.html is <script src="./inline.bundle.js"></script>. When I run the file in browser, it cannot find the file since the path is incorrect.

Comment: try to chnage value of base href in you index.html of dist folder

Answer (score 2):

**TO RESOLVE THIS ISSUE OF PROVIDING THE ABSOLUTE PATH**

> Please use the command below to generate the build of project using angular cli

Command
*for the dev build*

```
ng build --base-href ./
```

*for the production build*

```
ng build --prod --base-href ./
```

Base-href is used to notify the path of js file located at.

Comment: core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'file:///Users/keshavdhawan/Documents/sd/dist/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null' and URL 'file:///Users/keshavdhawan/Documents/sd/dist/index.html'.
Error: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'file:///Users/keshavdhawan/Documents/sd/dist/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null' and URL 'file:///Users/keshavdhawan/Documents/sd/dist/index.html'.

Comment: This one. ng build --base-href ./

Comment: I have also run this command its working fine in my case please. is that the error that you are getting in console or terminal. please try to run that command from the root directory

Comment: On terminal it is building fine. I am getting this error on console when I open index.html of dist folder.

Comment: And its just on chrome and firefox. I tested on safari, its working fine. May be a security issue.

Answer (score 1):

I used this and working fine:

```
ng build --base-href 'SERVER_APPLICATION_PATH'
```

LIKE AS

```
ng build --base-href 'http://localhost/web/angular-first/'
```